# Add shortcode attributes

Tags: wordpress

I am creating plugin in wordpress, in that I have used shortcode, so I required
to Combines user `shortcode` attributes with known attributes and fills in defaults when needed.

Comment: Ok. And what's the question Sanjay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should solve your problem

**shortcode_atts( $pairs , $atts, $shortcode );**

For more details Visit http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API